# How to fetch thousands of Records

Tags: spring-batch

I am a newbie to spring batch. I am trying to fetch thousands of records from a database.The database table has thousands (20000) of records. Can someone please help me. How can i fetch the records like 200 at time and store in a collection.

In JdbcCursorItemReader, I provided sql statement (SELECT x, y, z from ). Using ParameterizedRowMapper, I am trying to iterate the records.

Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: I think the best solution for you is to pratice with SB doing tutorial around the net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spring batch framework automatically does this for you. It process what is known as a chunk of records. If you set the chunk size too 200 it will process 200 records at a time (it gets the records, stores it in a list, passes one record at a time to the processor and finally pass the full list to the writer).

This magic property is called "commit-interval" and is explained very well in the documentation - https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/configureStep.html

I would suggest reading though the full document to get a basic understanding of Spring Batch. It's about 300 pages and is very easy to read and understand.

Comment: Thank you for the detail explanation. This is exactly what am i looking for.

Comment: But what if someone Wants to process 200 at a time?  So the next step in the process for example can be sent a bulk load of 200.

Comment: No the signature of the process method passes only item at a time. You can't get all 200 items together in the process step. In general you would not need it.